# Find file by name and unknown extension C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Are there any clever ways to easily find a file by its name and unknown extension in C#?

I have a image folder with images of different types .jpg, .gif and .png.
And all the program knows is the name of the image, and not the extension.

Is it possible to get the file by its name, without doing some big recursive resource consuming loop?

Comment: No. You'll have to do the loop. However, it isn't exactly resource consuming, appart from the required disk I/O of course. Also, have you considered the following scenario: what if two files exist with different extensions `foo1.jpg` and `foo2.png`? Make sure you can handle this.

Comment: How about System.IO.Path.GetExtension("A.txt") ?

Comment: For completeness, note that all answers so far will do "a loop" in one way or the other. Which is not a bad thing: in the end, there is just no way around that.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx) method and specify a search pattern:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\work", "somefilename.*");
```

This will of course return an `IEnumerable<string>` of all files that match this search pattern. If you know there can only be one, or wanted to get the first in the list, just chain it with LINQ to further filter the results.

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for. Thanks, I'll accept it in 8mins :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Use overloaded [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) method which accepts search pattern as second parameter:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\images", fileName + ".*");
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq to rescue

```
var filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\System32").Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).Where(fn => fn.StartsWith("ap"));
```

Let linq do the looping and filtering for you

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of options:

1. Build your file index in advance (simple dictionary will do the
   trick).
2. [Use windows search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266517%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
3. Use EnumerateFiles, altough performance wise this is similar to a bit optimized big recursion traverse.